# State scope in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm a beginner with Svelte and I have the following component:

```
<script>
  let svgSelector = null;

  const renderMap = () => {
    const map = document.getElementById("map");
    const mapContainer = document.getElementById("mapContainer");
    svgSelector = SVG().addTo(map);

    svgSelector
      .size(mapContainer.offsetWidth, mapContainer.offsetHeight)
      .viewbox(
        0,
        0,
        $activeLayer.background.width,
        $activeLayer.background.height
      );

    svgSelector.image($activeLayer.background.url);

    return svgSelector;
  };

  onMount(() => {
    renderMap();

    /* Logs the correct node */
    console.log(svgSelector)
  });

  /* Logs null */
  console.log(svgSelector)
</script>

<main>
  {#each $hotspots as hotspot}
     <Hotspot hotspot={hotspot} svgSelector={svgSelector} />
  {/each}
</main>
```

The renderMap function returns an SVG node which I will use in a child component.

I need to send that node down to the child component, but it's coming through as null.
How would one go about passing the node instead of the null value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delay the rendering of your child `Hotspot` components until `svgSelector` has a value, or guard against `svgSelector` having value `null` inside `Hotspot`.

**Example**

```html
{#if svgSelector}
  <main>
    {#each $hotspots as hotspot}
       <Hotspot hotspot={hotspot} svgSelector={svgSelector} />
    {/each}
  </main>
{/if}
```